# std::bad_alloc on retrieval from vector

Tags: c++, qt, stdvector, bad-alloc

(I've never asked a question here before so please excuse me if I don't follow proper etiquette)

I'm working on a scene graph for use in a GLWidget, and I'm running into a weird case of bad_alloc.  Each node (called a graphNode) in my scene graph has the following fields:

```
QString* name
graphNode* parent
std::vector<graphNode*> children
myPolygon* polygon
```

(myPolygon is a custom polygon class I created to store vertex and color data)

My SceneGraph class has the following fields:

```
graphNode* root
std::vector<graphNode*> allNodes
std::vector<myPolygon> allShapes
```

the bad_alloc occurs when I'm trying to build allNodes.  my root ndoe has 5 children, and if I use std::cout to print the size of the children vector I do get 5.  However, when I try to push each child to allNodes I get a std::bad_alloc error.  The exact Application ouput in QT is

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
what():  std::bad_alloc
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, especially since the program is recognizing that the children exist (and when I step through using print statements and the debugger I can see that the children are all what I expect them to be.  Any help would be greatly appreciated, and if I need to provide my code I would be more than glad to do so.

EDIT: Since someone asked, essentially I have some code that creates a character as follows:

Node Root:
        name "root"
        polygon = a rectangle for the torso
        graphNode* parent = NULL
        vector of 5 children [Head, Arm1, Arm2, Leg1, Leg2]

Node Head:
    name "head"
    polygon = a circle for the head
    graphNode* parent = root
    an empty children vector

Node Arm1
    name "arm1"
    polygon = a rectangle for the upper arm
    graphNode* parent = root
    vector of 1 child [Forearm1]

Node Arm2
    name "arm2"
    polygon = a rectangle for the upper arm
    graphNode* parent = root
    vector of 1 child [Forearm2]

Node Leg1
    name "leg1"
    polygon = a rectangle for the thigh
    graphNode* parent = root
    vector of 1 child [Loweleg1]

Node Leg2
    name "leg2"
    polygon = a rectangle for the thigh
    graphNode* parent = root
    vector of 1 child [Loweleg2]

Node Forearm1
    name "forearm1"
    polygon = a rectangle for the forearm
    graphNode* parent = Arm1
    an empty children vector

Node Forearm2
    name "forearm2"
    polygon = a rectangle for the forearm
    graphNode* parent = Arm2
    an empty children vector

Node Lowerleg1
    name "lowerleg1"
    polygon = a rectangle for the calf
    graphNode* parent = Leg1
    an empty children vector

Node Lowerleg2
    name "lowerleg2"
    polygon = a rectangle for the calf
    graphNode* parent = Leg2
    an empty children vector

Comment: `std::bad_alloc` means the program ran out of memory. It may occur during pushing because if the vector size grows beyond its current capacity, the vector has to allocate a bigger buffer

Comment: How does `root` come into this? And you might fire this through Valgrind just to see what bubbles up.

Comment: root is the base of the tree.  Essentially I'm drawing a really basic character as follows:

root node with a rectangle polygon for the torso and a vector of 5 graphNode* children:

2 arm nodes with rectangle myPolygons

2 leg nodes with rectangle myPolygons

a head node with a circle myPolygon

each arm node has a forearm node as a child

each leg node has a lower leg node as a child

Comment: Run it in a debugger and set a catchpoint on throw.

Comment: I'd suspect a bug in adding to *allNodes*. See how it grows. I'd verify it doesn't have some infinite loop/recursion, or adding itself to itself.

Comment: It's almost certainly a bug in your code, as @hyde suggested. If you post the code that copies the children of the root node into allNodes, we can probably tell you what's wrong.